# When to write custom Spring JPA Repositories vs just writing a custom Query

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to understand when one uses a "Custom" repository solution i.e creating one's own repository Vs just writing a custom Query using a @Query annotation on an arbitrary method in an already existing repository. There are so many ways to do this in Spring JPA, and I am trying to figure out how to choose. Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean "custom" repository? Do you mean using custom class with impl for method? Do you mean 1.3 Custom implementations for Spring Data repositories from here https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

Comment: Yes, that is correct.